# How to detect auto-replies in AWS SeS using events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SeS service to send emails and using SNS to track the events (Sent, delivery, OPen, etc).

Sometimes I receive the auto-replies, is there any event/any way to find mail is auto-reply?